# populate combobox c# in the background

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, combobox

I'm doing a project in `Visual Studio 2013` using `Windows Forms`.

I have a couple of forms (`LogIn`, `Meny`, `FakturaSokning` (For now))

When you start the program you open the `LogIn` and when you log in you go to the `Meny` where you can open the `FakturaSokning`.

Now to the problem i have.
I have 2 comboBoxes named `comboBoxFaktNr1` and `comboBoxFaktNr2` and I'm trying to populate them with the `FaktNr` i get from a SQL server. I connect to the server with

```
MigrateDBFakturaEntities db = new MigrateDBFakturaEntities();
```

and get the relevent information whith

```
var t = db.Fakturor.OrderBy(z => z.FaktNr).ToList();
```

the first thing i tried was doing a foreach loop

```
foreach (var item in t)
{
     comboBoxFaktNr1.Items.Add(item.FaktNr);
}
```

witch works but the problem with this was that it stopped responding untill it was done.

How can i have it eather fill the comboboxes in the background when opening the `FakturaSokning` Form and auto update the comboboxes when its done or do it when eather in the `Meny` or `LogIn` form?

If i missed some relative information tell me and i will try adding it as soon as possible.

Comment: How many items are you adding to the combo?

Comment: Using [`AddRange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than `Add()` to add all the items at once will help

Comment: The database i'm using now have about 17000 but it may be over 100000 later

Comment: That's just too many items. You need to rethink your UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the Backgroundworker which executes the operation on a seperate thread.

[Backgroundworker MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i have looked at that but i did not get it to work. i eather got no response or a error. Dont remember the exact error but it had something with you cant change comboboxes in another thread or something like that.

Comment: @Drago87 you can get round that by using `Invoke()`

Answer (score 1):

This seamd to have been the problem. Also the problem i had when trying to use it earlier was that i tried to make and use the worker manualy by code. But if i used the ToolBox and added a worker from there everything worked.
And this is the code i used in the DoWork

```
BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

                List<Fakturor> t = db.Fakturor.OrderBy(z => z.FaktNr).ToList();

                foreach (var item in t)
                {
                    comboBoxFaktNr1.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                        {
                            comboBoxFaktNr1.Items.Add(item.FaktNr);
                        }));

                }
```